# Java polymorphism in C++

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, syntax, initialization

This code throws an error:

```
class A {};
class B : public A {};

int main() {
    A instance = new B();
}
```

Error message:

```
void *operator new(unsigned int)
no suitable constructor exists to convert from "B *" to "A"
```

My first language was Java and I'm really confused about this. Every subclass can be treated as its motherclass because it derives everything, so why shouldn't they add the option to treat B like A?

Or is there a mistake in my syntax? I started learning C++ 3 weaks ago, it could be possible.

I wasn't able to find a solution with google or by searching through my tutorial, so please help me.

Comment: You need to read a textbook, unlike java in C++ pointer and variable not the same thing. Problem is not with inheritance, but that `A` and `A*` are different types.

Comment: Looks closely at the error message, and read up on pointers. `new` results in a `B*` which is different than a `B`. Similarly an `A` is different than an `A*`.

Comment: Did `A instance = new A();` work? That one has no inheritation.

Comment: _@Timon_ 1st thing you should forget about when switching from Java to C++ is using `new`. That should be one of the rarest operators used.

Comment: Another reason Java is terrible as a first language.

Comment: Ok, but how can I treat a B instance as an A instance?

Comment: I need it for my game. I have a vector of living enemies which treats everything from Skeletons to Slimes as Enemies, their base class.

Comment: @Timon Before start programming a game in C++ you should have a  look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how your code should look like in C++:

```
class A {};
class B : public A {};

int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<A> instance = std::make_unique<B>();
}
```

Comment: Or I could make `instance` `auto`. On Windows, I'd use `unique_ptr<A> instance = new B;` because `std::make_unique` does error checking and throws. This is just on Windows, though.